# Question regarding notation of cartesian product definition

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Is there any way to write this definition without the 'for every' by either replacing it by a sign or by formulating the definition differently so that it does not contain any words?

$$\prod_{i=1}^{n} M_{i} := \{(a_1,...,a_n)|a_i \in M_i \text{ for every } i \in \{1,...,n\}\}$$

Thank you!

Comment: $|\forall i\in\{1,2,...,n\} \; a_i\in M_i\}$

Comment: $\prod_{i=1}^nM_i = \{f\colon \{1,\ldots,n\}\to \cup_{i=1}^n M_i \mid \forall i\in\{1,\ldots,n\} (f(i)\in M_i)\}$.